# Correct regex for wp_embed_register_handler

Tags: php, html, oembed, regex, parse

**THE GOAL**

I'm trying to parse a url and convert it to an [embedded](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) video player in my post's content but I think my regEx is off or I'm not creating a [provider](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler) correctly.

**THE CODE**

Here is what I have setup now.

```
wp_embed_register_handler('brightcove', '/(players.brightcove.net/)([^/]+)/([^/]+)/index\.html\?videoId=([\d]+)/g', 'wp_embed_handler_brightcove');

function wp_embed_handler_brightcove($matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr) {

    // var_dump($matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr);

    $account  = esc_attr($matches[ 1 ]);
    $player   = esc_attr($matches[ 2 ]);
    $video_id = esc_attr($matches[ 3 ]);

    $embed = '<div style="display: block; position: relative; max-width: 142.86%;"><div style="padding-top: 39.3742%;"><iframe src="'
    . sprintf('http://players.brightcove.net/%1$s/%2$s/index.html?videoId=%3$s',
              $account,
              $player,
              $video_id
    ) . '" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px;"></iframe></div></div>';

    return apply_filters('embed_brightcove', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr);
}
```

---

**TESTING**

```
$embed_code = wp_oembed_get('http://players.brightcove.net/1234567890123/default_default/index.html?videoId=1234567789012');

echo $embed_code; // nothing :(
```

I do have a regEx working on [regexr](http://regexr.com) which uses:

`(players.brightcove.net/)([^/]+)/([^/]+)/index\.html\?videoId=([\d]+)`

and looks for:

`http://players.brightcove.net/{account}/{player_id}/index.html?videoId={video_Id}`

**RESOURCES**

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php
- http://regexr.com

**THE QUESTION**

How can I get this custom embed handler to function correctly? Can I fix my regEx or am I not calling the methods correctly?

---

**UPDATE: Experiment**

I ran into [VerbalExpressions](http://www.javascriptoo.com/verbalexpressions) a while ago and I wanted to see how this might work. The PHP version is [here](https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/PHPVerbalExpressions), but this is using the JS version that I can test on [RegExr](http://regexr.com) or [RegEx101](https://regex101.com):

```
var tester = VerEx()
        .startOfLine()
        .maybe("http")
        .maybe("s")
        .maybe(":")
        .then("//players.brightcove.net/")
        .word()
        .then('/')
        .word()
        .then('/index.html?videoId=')
        .word()
        .maybe('&')
        .anythingBut(" ")
        .endOfLine();
```

Although it compiles down to something that works, it still needs some cleanup. Essential only making groups of the things I'm interested in and converting some orignal groups to non-matching groups.

```
// Before

/^(http)(s)?(\:\/\/players\.brightcove\.net\/)\w+(\/)\w+(\/index\.html\?videoId\=)\w+(\&)?([^\ ]*)$/gm

// After

/^(?:http)?(?:s)?(?:\:)?\/\/players\.brightcove\.net\/(\d+)\/(\w+)\/index\.html\?videoId\=(\d+)\&?[^\ ]*$/gm
```

---

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

Modified slightly from [@birgire's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214022/84219) because account will always be numeric.

```
wp_embed_register_handler(
    'brightcove',
    '#https?://players\.brightcove\.net/([\d]+)/([^/]+)/index\.html\?videoId=([\d]+)#', 
    'wp_embed_handler_brightcove');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just few notes here:

- We have to be careful using `%` within `sprintf()` to avoid confusion with the *placeholders*. Try to remove the CSS styles.
- It's sometimes easier to use the `#` or `~` *delimiters* in regular expressions, instead of the `/` delimiter.
- Since you have the `(players.brightcove.net/)` as the first match, it might not match this assumption:

  ```
  $account  = esc_attr( $matches[1] );
  ```

  Try instead:

  ```
  #https?://players\.brightcove\.net/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/index\.html\?videoId=([\d]+)#
  ```

This seems to work in the content editor:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    wp_embed_register_handler( 
       'brightcove', 
       '#https?://players\.brightcove\.net)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/index.html\?videoId=([\d]+)#', 
       'wp_embed_handler_brightcove' 
    );
} );
```

where `wp_embed_handler_brightcove()` is the callback function defined by @jgraup above.

Here's a related [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/201841/26350) I worked on recently.

### Playing with PHPVerbalExpressions

@jgraup [mentioned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214007/correct-regex-for-wp-embed-register-handler/214022?noredirect=1#comment314601_214022) the library [*PHPVerbalExpressions - "PHP Regular expressions made easy"*](https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/PHPVerbalExpressions).

Here's an attempt to use it:

```
$regex = new \VerbalExpressions\PHPVerbalExpressions\VerbalExpressions();

$regex->removeModifier( 'm' )
//      ->startOfLine()
      ->then( 'http' )
      ->maybe( 's' )
      ->then( '://players.brightcove.net/' )
      ->anythingBut( '/' )
      ->then( '/' )
      ->anythingBut( '/' )
      ->then( '/index.html?videoId=' )
      ->add( '([\d]+)' );
//      ->endOfLine();
```

This generates the following pattern:

```
/(?:http)(?:s)?(?:\:\/\/players\.brightcove\.net\/)(?:[^\/]*)(?:\/)(?:[^\/]*)(?:\/index\.html\?videoId\=)([\d]+)/
```

or if we expand it:

```
/
   (?:http)
   (?:s)?
   (?:\:\/\/players\.brightcove\.net\/)
   (?:[^\/]*)
   (?:\/)
   (?:[^\/]*)
   (?:\/index\.html\?videoId\=)
   ([\d]+)
/
```

We would have to adjust the matched keys accordingly with `$matches`.

Comment: ps: I don't think wp_oembed_get() is using any cache, so you might want to double check that further, I could be remembering  that wrong so late.

Comment: I was only using it in the debug console but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: ok sounds good ;-)

Comment: I forgot about this project but it might help in the future - https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/PHPVerbalExpressions

Comment: Thanks for that link @jgraup - I attempted to use it here ;-) I didn't find a way to rewrite `([\d]+)` other than using `->add( '([\d]+)' )`. I wanted to rewrite this in the easy language, using e.g. `->range( 0,9 )` or even a second class instance to generate it, but that didn't work so well ;-)

Comment: When I tried this mine ends up looking more like: `/^[http]?[s]?[\:]?\/\/players\.brightcove\.net\/(\d+)\/(\w+)\/index\.html\?videoId\=(\d+)\&?[^\ ]*$/gm` - but I haven't tested in PHP. Essentially, make https: optional, `d` for ID `w` for player ID and optional extra stuff on the url that will be ignored.

Comment: Just another side note. I used this site to quickly create the expression http://www.javascriptoo.com/verbalexpressions then tested on http://regexr.com because I didn't want to have to keep hitting reload for php ;-) Looks like they make a lot of groups `( )` which can be removed or replaced with `[ ]` so as to not be included in the final matches.

Comment: `.range('0', '9')` looks ok, but it's only for a single char. They need to add a `.repeat()` which converts to `+`

Comment: yes it looks like the library could be more flexible, e.g. regarding the groups and numbers. Would also like to see a way to combine multiple regex instances into a single one. But this kind of approach could help keep the code more understandable and thus reduce errors @jgraup