# How to add new embed handler not supported by oembed?

Tags: functions, embed

I am looking to embed videos from websites that do not offer oembed support. I wrote some code but it's not working.

example link:

```
https://openload.co/f/onU1gT5mkJ8/A_date_with_Lazar_Angelov.mp4
```

example embed:

```
<iframe src="https://openload.co/embed/onU1gT5mkJ8/A_date_with_Lazar_Angelov.mp4" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="700" height="430" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

my code:

```
  add_action( 'init', function()
    {
        wp_embed_register_handler( 
            'openload', 
            '#https://www\.openload\.co/f/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?#i', 
            'wp_embed_handler_openload' 
        );

    } );

    function wp_embed_handler_openload( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr )
    {
        $embed = sprintf(
            '<iframe class="openload-video" src="https://openload.co/embed/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="700" height="430" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">></iframe>',
            esc_attr( $matches[1] ) 
         );

        return apply_filters( 'embed_openload', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
    }
```

I really stucked at this. I would much appreciate any advice or links to any info that can help. Thanks!

Comment: I answered a similar question (same title) recently [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/201841/26350) that's hopefully helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it's the fact you're trying to use the regex pattern in your `sprintf` call, when you should be using... well, a [`sprintf` format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$embed = sprintf(
    '<iframe class="openload-video" src="https://openload.co/embed/%s" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="700" height="430" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">></iframe>',
    esc_attr(
        $matches[1]
    ) 
);
```

Note that you're not using `www` in your embed url:

```
https://openload.co/f/onU1gT5mkJ8/A_date_with_Lazar_Angelov.mp4
```

as expected in your pattern:

```
#https://www\.openload\.co/f/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?#i
```

Comment: yes this is definitely needed here or %1$s