# How do I include and iframe in a Custom Block?

Tags: block-editor, iframe

Given the html block tag I can include and iframe from Google My Maps in my post.

I need to create a block where the client can paste the URL from the embed code and the block render the iframe.

*note: "embed code" does not mean using the `embed` tag, but that is what the iframe code is called to embed the map on a web page.*

I have attempted with Genesis Custom Blocks but it will not render the iframe.

Comment: what you're describing sounds like OEmbed, iframes are stripped out for security reasons

Comment: Note that Google Maps does not support oEmbed, so supporting pasting a URL and generating an iframe embed is probably not possible.

Comment: Thank you both. @TomJNowell, that is precisely my problem. As stated, I can insert an iframe through the html block in the editor and it is rendered. I am attempting to create a custom block similar to the Youtube video block where the src URL is pasted and the iframe is rendered. I am not able to discover how the html block bypasses core stripping out the iframe.

Comment: it doesn't bypass it, youtube etc use the OEmbed API, you can't insert a raw iframe into post content as it's a security breach (some users may think they can, but this is because they're super administrators with the `unfiltered_html` capability which lets them do dangerous insecure things, any HTML they insert would get stripped out). Remember, the HTML block lets you insert custom HTML, not arbitrary/any HTML, you're still limited to the HTML tag whitelist.

Comment: Oh! I just verified this with an author-level account. So, as superadmin I can place an iframe in the HTML block and it is rendered, but, other users are restricted from adding frames because they are not on the HTML whitelist and the code is likely being filtered when run through the cusom block!

Comment: You might think to give that capability to other roles - but that's generally inadvisable. Ideally you would create a custom block from scratch (or fine a premade one) which fulfills this role rather than using one which relies on end-user input of markup.

Comment: Maybe registering it as a custom embed handler https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/201841/26350